# Prevent file overwriting in pre-create-callback / post-create-callback

Tags: windows, driver, minifilter

I write minifilter driver which is intended to prevent writing into PE files. I check file contents in post-create callback. If format has matched I try to call `FltCancelFileOpen` and return `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`.

But this can be hijacked by opening file with `CreateDisposition = FILE_OVERWRITE/FILE_OVERWRITE/FILE_SUPERSEDE`. In this case the file is already truncated at the moment of calling post-create-callback.

How to overcome this?

Comment: Couldn't you check whether the file exists before letting the file system attempt to create it, and if it does, check the file format and if necessary reject the request immediately?

Answer (score 1):

Better option will be check in pre-create callback and deny file opens with write access for existing files. You can do that by returning `FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE` from pre-create and setting appropriate error in `CallbackData->IoStatus.Status`.

Comment: It is unfeasible to issue another file-open operation in pre-create callback. Also, file opening can fail in pre-create due to file name tunneling in FAT and NTFS file systems. I think it is more appropriate to replace FILE_OVERWRITE/FILE_SUPERSEDE to FILE_OPEN, FILE_OVERWRITE_IF to FILE_OPEN_IF (same dispositions without truncating) in pre-create. Then check file contents in post-create and emulate file truncating for FILE_OVERWRITE/FILE_SUPERSEDE/FILE_OVERWRITE_IF.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 FltCancelFileOpen( FltObjects->Instance, FltObjects->FileObject );
 Data->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
 Data->IoStatus.Information = 0;
```

and return

```
FLT_POSTOP_FINISHED_PROCESSING;
```

full example at scanner example of microsoft at GitHub